# locally finite open cover

Tags: general-topology, compactness

I attended a topology class. My lecturer said that if a space is not compact then we can define locally finite symmetric neighbourhood. Note that a neighbourhood $U(x)$ of $x$ is said symmetric if $y \in U(x)$ then $x \in U(y)$. The proof  is given as follows:

Suppose $X$ is not compact. So there is a countable, closed, discrete set $\{x_n: n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ of $X$. Let $f: X \rightarrow [1,\infty)$ be a continuous function such that $f(x_n) =n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Put $W_1 =f^{-1}([1,3/2))$, $W_2 =f^{-1}((5/4,7/4))$, $W_3 =f^{-1}((3/2,5/2))$, $W_4 =f^{-1}((9/4,11/4))$,....

The collection $\mathcal{W} =\{W_n:n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is an open cover of $[1, \infty)$ and $\{st(x, \mathcal{W}): x \in X\}$ is locally finite.

I do not understand why is $\{st(x, \mathcal{W}): x \in X\}$ locally finite? If the function $f$ is injective then I agree that $\{st(x, \mathcal{W}): x \in X\}$ is locally finite. So, my question is: can we always be able define a injective continuous function $f: X \rightarrow [0,\infty)$ satisfying above condition?

Comment: The notation $st(x, \mathcal{W} )$ is not standard: what does it mean?

Comment: @Crostul $st(x, \mathcal{W} = \cup\{W \in \mathcal{W}: x \in W\}$.

Comment: What is U(y)???

Comment: @WilliamElliot $U(y)$ is neighbourhood of $y$. Actually $U$ is an assignment from a space $X$ to its topology such that $x \in U(x)$ for all $x \in X$.

Comment: @hidup.  Just any open set?  U(y) is simply the whole space?  What topological space;  this problem is looking like a neighbourhood space problem.

Comment: What is $X$? Who is your teacher? Why does $\mathcal W$ have anything to do with $[1,\infty)$, and not with $X$, where $X$ need not have intervals as it may not be a linear order? Why should $W_1$ be considered open, when $[1,3/2)$ is not open in $[0,\infty)$. Would you please read what you wrote and edit it to make it more consistent? What do the dots mean in your definition of $W_n$, that pattern may not be entirely obvious from the first four terms only?